# Name of sacrificial plastic chain link/carabiner/loop "insert" which reduces friction

Tags: fitting, swing, chain

I've seen these small round plastic inserts on swing/hammock hanging kits. Anyone know what they are called so that I can search where to buy them? Or perhaps what material they are typically made from in case it is possible to 3D print. Need to replace my broken ones and retrofit on other fittings.

Images below are from various hardware stores when searching for "swing hanging kit".

Image from [here](https://online.depo-diy.lt/product/7933):

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.amazon.de/AMAZONAS-Deckenhaken-kugelgelagert-H%C3%A4ngesessel-Verl%C3%A4ngerungskette/dp/B000OY3DVU):

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.diy.com/departments/carabiner/1926595_BQ.prd):

[image]

Comment: I presume these images are ones you grabbed from the internet? If so, A) please provide attribution for where you got the images, and B) what search terms did you use to find them?

Comment: The plastic material is probably nylon type plastic.

Comment: search `bushing`

Comment: @FreeMan Oops, I initially pasted the image URL directly from the retailer website, but it made a copy instead of a direct link. Added the attribution now.

Comment: Middle one looks to be a slice of tubing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function of the insert, in the cabling world, is to provide for a smooth transition on the cable wrapped around the outer diameter. It appears that this particular application may be a modified use of what is known as a thimble.

Using search terms "round plastic thimble" returns results that confirm the product shape, not necessarily the application:

[image: round plastic thimble]

Image from [knotandrope.com](https://www.knotandrope.com/collections/rope-tools/products/round-plastic-thimble-heavy-duty-1) website.

Other sites have similar images.

3D printing such an item may not be useful, as durability would be minimal, unless printed in nylon or similar material.

Comment: This is perfect! Various search combinations of "chain/rope/carabiner" + "plastic thimble" give me exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The name of this part is "bearing."
In your case it is plastic, so it is called "plastic bearing."